# SQL employee database querying Questions

Tags: sql

SQL  employee  database  querying  Questions

Consider the employee database of an organization XYZ private limited

[image]

```
                 ______________Questions ________________
```

[image]

Answers that I have been able to do

Question 1

write a query where top 5 country where highest paid employees are based

```
select top 5 (c.name, sum(s.amount) as high_sal)
from countries as c
join salary as s on c.id=s.id
group by c.name
order by high_sal desc
```

Question 2

Write a query to extract count of users in age group 18-25, 26-40, 41-60 and 60+
respectively. Also, find highest paid in each group.

```
Select  DATEDIFF(YY,E.dob,GETDATE()) AS age,max(salary),
Case 
 when age >=18 and age<=25  then ‘18-25’ 
when age >=26 and age<=40 then ‘26-40’
when age >=41 and age<=60 then ‘41-60’
when age >=61 then ‘60 plus’
END AS category,
count(category)
From Employees  AS E 
JOIN SALARY AS S
GROUP BY category
Order by age
```

another possible answer

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as '18-25', MAX(salary) as 'Highest Paid in 18-25'
FROM users
WHERE age BETWEEN 18 AND 25
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as '26-40', MAX(salary) as 'Highest Paid in 26-40'
FROM users
WHERE age BETWEEN 26 AND 40
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as '41-60', MAX(salary) as 'Highest Paid in 41-60'
FROM users
WHERE age BETWEEN 41 AND 60
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as '60+', MAX(salary) as 'Highest Paid in 60+'
FROM users
WHERE age>60;
```

question 3

The Previous_Employment_Details table will contain details of all the past companies
that the employee has worked at. Write a query to extract the list of employees who last
worked at TCS just before joining the current company.

```
SELECT u.name
FROM users u
INNER JOIN Previous_Employment_Details p 
ON u.user_id = p.user_id
WHERE p.company_name = 'TCS'
ORDER BY p.date_of_joining DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Question 5

Write a query to extract the Top 3 highest paying companies (Previous Employment)
along with their locations. Include designation with the salary of the employee.

```
SELECT p.company_name, p.location, p.designation, p.salary
FROM Previous_Employment_Details p
ORDER BY p.salary DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: yes second image

Comment: Please anyone who has any idea 
pls help

Comment: What is you question about this homework ? see: "**Providing an answer that doesn't help a student learn is not in the student's own best interest**. Therefore you might choose to treat homework questions differently than other questions." ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/724039))

Comment: Yes actually I'm trying to learn but you can help me with my answers if they are right or wrong

Comment: I just need guidance so i can get to the right Pls

Comment: This site is there to review code: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

Question 3
Ans

```
Select employees_id
From previous_employment_details
Where company_id="TCS"
```

Answer (score 2):

Question 4

Answer is somewhat like this
Im not sure

```
Select e.id, s.amount , e. Joined_at, e.email ,s.lastdrwn, c.name
From employee e , salary s, companies c
```